# How do you use an if else and check for last character '\0' of a string?

Tags: c

In C apparently strings are stored like an array with a null value or '\0' at the end. I wish to iterate over the string in a for loop and I need it to stop at '\0', not including it. I've tried many conditions for the if else and it all don't seem to work.

for example:

```
char patternInput[TEXTSIZE];

for(int i = 0; i<strlen(patternInput);i++)
{
    if(patternInput[i]==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nlast character");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%c",patternInput[i]);
    }
}
```

I've tried `if(patternInput[i]==NULL)`, `if(patternInput[i]==NUL)`,`if(!patternInput[i])`,`if(patternInput[i]=='\0')` and none of them seems to work.

Comment: `strlen` doesn't include the terminating 0 in the length. You'll never get there with that loop.

Comment: `NULL` is the wrong thing to check against. You want `0` or `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're scanning the characters yourself, you can avoid the (redundant and somewhat expensive) `strlen()` call entirely, and instead use the value of `patternInput[i]` in the continuation-test of your for-loop:

```
char patternInput[TEXTSIZE] = "testing!";

for(int i = 0; patternInput[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   printf("\n%c",patternInput[i]);
}
printf("\nlast character\n");
```

Comment: 1) Ok so my problem is a little more complicated. I'm doing a function that checks if a string is in a sentence without using strstr. Basically, I'll input a sentence, first, then input a string. I use a forloop and iterate over the sentence until that iteration character of the sentence matches the first character of my string. If it matches (using an if else), I'll use a nested forloop and loop over the string, checking the third, fourth, fifth characters. My problem is I need to know if it reaches the '\0' value to know if it truly matches, so I have to have an if else statement to check

Comment: 2) for the null or '\0' value. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @WerWer The example given in this answer provides a template for you. Just replace `patternInput` with `searchWord`, and check inside the loop against `sentenceInput[search_position + i]`.

Comment: @aghast There's a searchWord function in C?

Comment: @WerWer: You don't necessarily need to check for '\0' character for the end of the string. You can maintain the length of the matched string so far and if it becomes equal to the length of the pattern then you know its a match.

Comment: @ashish.g bruh you are a genius, that fixed everything

Comment: @WerWer Thanks. Also, to your original question i have posted an answer too. Do check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code. This code prints 'Null character found' with position of the character. Notice the 'less than or equal to' in `i<=strlen(str)` in the loop invariant.

The last character at the length strlen + 1 is the '\0' character.

```
int i = 0;
    
char str[] = "Hello";
    
for(int i=0; i<=strlen(str); i++)
{
    if(str[i]=='\0')
        printf("Null character found at position %d", i);
}
```